# How to upload one sigle image with ajax (jQuery)

Tags: ajax, file-upload, upload

I'm making a website which write some data to MySQL database. With all the data i want to upload one image. There's no need to crop or resize the image. Just upload it.

Here's some source.

```
                    data = "project_name=" + project_name + ....            

                    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'insert_project_src.php',
        data: insertproject,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response)
        {
            if(response==0)
            {
                $("#error").html("Error ocoured");
                $("#error").fadeIn(1500);
            }
            else if(response==1)
            {
                $("#error").html("Project inserted");
                $("#error").fadeIn(1500);
            }
        }
        })
```

Does anybody know how to do it?
Feel free to ask anything.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, this is not JavaScript, but I like [SWFupload library](http://www.swfupload.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one. http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Uploadify is a powerful and highly-customizable file upload script. In its simplest form, Uploadify is easy to get up and running with minimal effort and little coding knowledge.

Uploadify can also be modified to suits the needs of more advanced developers via the arsenal of custom options that are available. Below are a few examples of different implementations of the Uploadify plugin. Uploadify is fully customizable and mainly all browser compatible.

Good luck.